# How do I define a generic constraint so that I can use the ?? coalesing operator

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to define a generic class

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TDatabase, TKey, T> : IRepository<TKey, T> 
    where T : class
    where TDatabase : IDatabase
{
    private TDatabase db;

    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;

    protected IDatabaseFactory<TDatabase> DatabaseFactory { get; private set; }

    protected TDatabase Database
    {
        get
        {
            return db ?? (db = DatabaseFactory.Get());
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

On the line `return db ?? (db = DatabaseFactory.Get());`, the compiler is complaining with "Left operand of the '??' operator should be of reference or nullable type"

I understand the error, but don't know how to put a constraint on the TDatabase type parameter so that the compiler knows it is a reference or nullable type.

How to I make the compiler happy?

Comment: Ah, just realized I needed `where TDatabase : class, IDatabase`

Comment: Wouldn't you just want: return db ?? DatabaseFactory.Get(); here?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald not necessarily, it's a lazy load pattern sort of.

Comment: Interesting, I can see kind of how it could be a lazy load kind of thing, but could you explain it to me? I'm curious to know if I could receive some form of performance/memory benefits by using such n approach.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald By saving it into the field `db`, I don't have to go back to the DatabaseFactory to get another instance of the object next time I need it.

Comment: Surely that's the same as 'db ?? DatabaseFactory.Get();' though? You'd only be calling the factory if db was null.

Comment: Yes, but the assignment of `db = DatabaseFactory.Get()` is what makes `db` be not null in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to indicate that `TDatabase` is a reference type

```
where TDatabase : class, IDatabase
```

---

[MSDN, Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> **where T : class**  The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

[MSDN, ?? Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator and is used to
>   define a default value for nullable value types or reference types. It
>   returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it
>   returns the right operand.

Answer (score 1):

```
where TDatabase : class, IDatabase
```

Comment: It can't be the other round. 'class' constraint has to the be first constraint

Comment: Couldn't remember the order off the top of my head, now corrected

Answer (score 1):

Can you change you constraint to include `class`?

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TDatabase, TKey, T> : IRepository<TKey, T>  
    where T : class 
    where TDatabase : class, IDatabase 
{
    //... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TDatabase, TKey, T> : IRepository<TKey, T>
    where T : class
    where TDatabase : class, IDatabase
{
}
```